# From Jenkins, how to access to a secured repository in GitBlit (over http(s))?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitblit

I use GitBlit (1.3.2), Jenkins (1.534) on RedHat 6

I created a Git repository on a local GitBlit. Access is restricted to authenticated users. This works fine.

When I try to configure a new job in Jenkins to enable continuous Integration, I enter the Git repository URL as follow:

```
http://jenkins@myhost.local/gitblit/git/testing/secured_repo.git
```

I received the error message below and I don't know where to set the jenkins's password...

`Failed to connect to repository : Failed to connect to http://jenkins@myhost.local/gitblit/git/testing/secured_repo.git (status =
401)`

Help is very welcome!

Comment: No solution yet? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: @GerritBrouwer: no... I decided to wait version 1.5, GitBlit should support SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try including the password in your url:

```
http://jenkins:password@myhost.local/gitblit/git/testing/secured_repo.git
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work using Jenkins 1.560 and gitblit 1.5.0 if you add the credentials to Jenkins(Global Credentials) and use JGit(if the installed version of git doesn't support **git config  --local**) You can probably use native git if you have a more recent version(>=1.7.9).

Url would be http://myhost.local/gitblit/git/testing/secured_repo.git

Then either select credentials from the dropdown or add new credentials.

Comment: your solution work on my side. thanks. Jenkins 1.643 & Gitblit 1.6.2

Comment: Yes, leaving out the uid:pwd@ from the authority part of the URL and specifying it using Jenkins credentials did the trick for me. So in stead of using the URLhttp://jenkins@myhost.local/gitblit/git/testing/secured_repo.git you should use it without specifying the user http://myhost.local/gitblit/git/testing/secured_repo.git

Answer (score 0):

Use `.netrc` in folder `/var/lib/jenkins`

```
machine host
login user
password yourpassword
```

Comment: Good idea the permanent authentication, but unfortunately GitBlit doesn't support this authentication...

Comment: @Destroyica Actually gitblit seems to do exactly that. I'm sitting with the exact same error at the moment and after adding the .netrc file I can clone repositories through the cmd line as the jenkins user. However, it seems the jenkins server still can't.

Comment: @m__: have you use the git plugin on Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin